# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded .. parameterized constructor

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function Employee(firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }

  Employee.prototype.goToWork = function(){
    console.log("I go to office daily!");
  };

  Employee.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
  };

  function Developer(firstName,project) {
    Employee.call(this, firstName);

    this.project = project;
  };

  Developer.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);    
  Developer.prototype.constructor = Developer;                

  Developer.prototype.sayHello = function(){                  //overrides sayHello()
    console.log("Hello, I'm developer " + this.firstName + ". I'm in "
            + this.project + "project.");
  };

  Developer.prototype.developCode = function(){               
    console.log("I am developing code.");
  };

  $(".developerOK").click(function(){

    var name=$(".developerName").val();
    var project=$(".developerProject").val();
    var Developer1 = new Developer(name,project);
    Developer1.sayHello();
    Developer1.goToWork();
    Developer1.developCode();

  }); 

  function Manager(firstName,project) {
  setTimeout(Manager.call(this,firstName),5);

  this.project = project;
 };

 Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype); 

 Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;

 Manager.prototype.sayHello = function(){
   console.log("Hello, I'm manager " + this.firstName + ". I'm in "
            + this.project + "project.");
 };

 Manager.prototype.manageTeam = function(){
    console.log("I manage team.");
 };

 $(".managerOK").click(function(){

    var name=$(".managerName").val();
    var project=$(".managerProject").val();

    var Manager1 = new Manager(name,project);

    Manager1.sayHello();
    Manager1.goToWork();
    Manager1.manageTeam(); 

 });

});
```

When i click on `managerOK` button , it gives uncaught range error on `manager.call()`
I tried using `setTimeout()` but as my constructor is parametrized, I am not able to call it without parantheses.
Please help.

Comment: `function Manager(firstName,project) { setTimeout(Manager.call(this,firstName),5); this.project = project;};` this constructor obviously calls itself.

Comment: I got solution. Instead of Manager.call(),that should be Employee.call(). :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see your problem. You are calling the Manager constructor asynchronously within itself, causing a stack overflow:

```
function Manager(firstName,project) {
  setTimeout(Manager.call(this,firstName),5);

  this.project = project;
};
```

This is a common problem and I've seen several variations of it. The manager is supposed to be assigned something 5 milliseconds later. Could it be one of your other types - Employee or Developer?

Hope that helps!